# sprintf equivalent for xtend

Tags: string-formatting, printf, xtend

Is it possible to format strings in xtend? I am looking for something just like sprintf in C.

I tried using the String.format in java but I don't know why it is not available in xtend.
Maybe, they have something similar?

Answer (score 3):

You can create nicely formatted strings (including line breaks, etc.) using the [XPand language](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/?project=xpand) inline in XText, thus:

```
val myVar = 'Hello, world!'
println('''This is a string referring to a variable: «myVar».

It will print out «myVar?.length ?: 0» characters, as the 
variable «IF myVar == null»is«ELSE»is not«ENDIF» null.''')
```

If you need access to Java's `String.format` function, remember that static members are access using a double-colon, thus:

```
val formatted = String::format("Value: %1$.2f", 3.142)
```